# Create a table dynamically with fixed col width in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html-table, fixed-width

I create a table dynamically by JS with table-layout and width both **fixed**. And also set the columns' width to a fixed value in pixels. But the created table is not rendered according to the intention in IE7.It seems width property in col doesn't work. But it works both in FF and Chrome.

The created table with following dom structure:

```
<table id="dynamicTable" cellspacing="0" width="282px" style="table-layout: fixed; overflow: hidden;">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="129px">
        <col width="76px">
        <col width="76px">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>head1-1</td><td>head1-2</td><td>head1-3</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">head2-1,2</td><td>head2-3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>head3-1</td><td>head3-2</td><td>head3-3</td></tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

and css:

```
table {
    border-style: solid solid none none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #c0c0c0;
}
td {
    border-style: none none solid solid;
    border-width: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-color: #000 #000 #c0c0c0 #c0c0c0;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
#dynamicTable {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

**DEMO**

[html in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/icegit/1)

Can anybody explain the behavior in IE7?

Comment: `table-layout: fixed` isn't supported in IE7

Comment: Col width in IE7 is specified to content width, while in other browsers it specified to sum(content width + border width + padding width). In above table's structure, row's count width is larger than table's width. That may be the reason for the issue.